# Show that every finite plane graph where every vertex has even degree has a 2-face colouring.

Tags: graph-theory

I want to attempt to do this by using induction on the number of edges. Trivially it holds for $K_3$ and then if you remove two edges from a boundary of a face with the outer edge. Apply the Induction Hypothesis and then close the boundary and alternate the colour. How do I write this explicitly though? I'm confused as to how to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is good idea: removing edges changes the degrees of vertices, some may become odd, so applying the inductive hypothesis won't be possible.

**Hint:**

- Consider the dual graph.
- Do cycles of odd length exist in it?
- Prove that the dual graph is bipartite.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$